# Configure screenshots file names for Rails5/RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

It looks like for Rails5/RSpec systems tests, the default is to use `selenium-webdriver` gem to take screenshots when a spec fails.  Is there a way to configure the format of the filename for the screen shot that gets taken?  I've seen this is possible with `capybara-screenshot` gem, but I'm not sure how to do it with `selenium-webdriver`.

Basically, the default naming is failing to save the screenshot, because the default file names that get generated are too long, because they use the spec description to create the file.  This is the error I'm seeing:

`Errno::ENAMETOOLONG: File name too long @ rb_sysopen`

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is not actually for Rails 5, but it may be of use if someone is looking for solution in Rails 7.

The file name for screenshot created inside Rails is actually configured by `AcionDispatch::SystemTesting::TestHelpers::ScreenshotHelper`. In case of tool long file name, one way of dealing with problem is overriding `image_name` method and returning shorter name.

First create module with new method in *lib/core_ext/action_dispatch/system_testing/test_helpers/screenshot_helper_short_image_name.rb*:

```
module CoreExt::ActionDispatch::SystemTesting::TestHelpers::ScreenshotHelperShortImageName
    private

    def image_name
        super[0...120]
    end
end
```

(insert string length that can fit on oyur file system, 120 is just example).

Then in *config/initializers/system_test_case.rb* prepend created module:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load :action_dispatch_system_test_case do
    prepend CoreExt::ActionDispatch::SystemTesting::TestHelpers::ScreenshotHelperShortImageName
end
```

Unless you're on Rails >= 7.1 make sure, that *config/application.rb* contains:

```
config.autoload_lib(ignore: %w(assets tasks))
```

to autoload files from *lib/* directory.

Similar method can be used to change default file name given to screenshot files created on test failures. One can for example override method `ScreenshotHelper#unique` to include date/time of failure or seed of test run (`Minitest.seed`).

Answer (score -1):

In your tests, use

```
save_screenshot("tmp/screenshots/name-of-file.png")
```

Which will save it with that filename and in the default screenshot location.

Comment: The question is about modifying file name automatically generated by Rails on test failure, not about saving screenshot as a part of test.

Answer (score -2):

According to the docs, if you use `page.save_screenshot` you can pass in your own filename:

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/DriverExtensions/TakesScreenshot.html#save_screenshot-instance_method

Comment: how do you set it up so that it uses the name of the example?

Comment: That sounds like a new question... :)

Comment: The question is about modifying file name automatically generated by Rails on test failure, not about saving screenshot as a part of test.

Comment: It's been some time since I wrote this answer...

But the point i was trying to make (and likely that of the other commenter) is that if you choose to use save_screenshot, you can bypass the problem encountered, by defining your own filename at the time of your choosing.

It fixes the problem underlying the question, rather than fixing the symptom mentioned in the question.